# Running a TestNG class via testng.xml in Eclipse (Windows)

Tags: eclipse, testng

I have a class named "ATestClass" and it has some methods such as "launchSite", "loginToSite" etc.

Now, I want to control the order of execution of these methods. So, I created an xml file "testng.xml" as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  <suite name="Classes" verbose="10">
   <test name="ATestClass" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
     <class name="ATestClass" >
      <methods>
        <include name="launchSite" />
        <include name="searchAndExport" />
        <include name="loginToSite" />
      </methods>
     </class>
   </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Now, my class doesn't care this xml file and executes the methods in alphabetical order. I created both class and xml file in the same package.

Somehow, the class is not able to recognize its corresponding xml config file.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of TestNG? Make sure you are.

Comment: My bad, i was running the class directly as TestNG. Now I am running it from xml file  (right click -> run as  -> testng). But getting error: "Cannot find class in classpath: ATestClass". help me!!!!